# How can I use the same name for singular and plural form in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-1

I have a type `media`. I would like to use that name for both the singular and the plural forms. but I am struggling to figure out how to do so. I imaging it is by adjusting `Ember.Inflector` but I have sent every variation at it that I can think of with no luck.

Note: I am currently stuck on Ember 1.13, and upgrading it really isn't feasible right now.

Comment: Have you tried `Inflector.inflector.irregular('media', 'media');`?

Comment: I have tried that but it seems to break items that return multiple. So fixes some problems creates new ones.

Comment: how does it break?

Comment: One specific example when it is nested on a another type say foo and the response comes back {media: [], foo: { media_id: '1' }} it fails to load the media records into the store properly.

Comment: what serializer? should be fixable there. this doesnt look like standard `JSON:API`